# How can I get the correct store context in the product save observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-enterprise, event-observer, multistore

I'm using the observer called `catalog_product_save_after` to track changes to a product. Whenever this observer fires, I don't have access to the store context. I would like to get only the store contexts that the product has been modified in.

How can I get only the stores that a product has been modified for in the `catalog_product_save_after` event observer?

Comment: can you show code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A product can only be saved for one store at a time. So when saving a product, you are always in the context of a single store. The store id can be retrieved from the `Varien_Event_Observer` observer argument as follows:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getStoreId()
```

Note that saving an attribute value for a product in one store can have an impact on attribute value of the corresponding attribute for the same product in another store.

For instance, consider saving a product with id `123` for store `0`(the admin store), and in which the attribute `name` (with attribute id `71`) has been changed. When loading product id `123` again for store `1` (the default frontend store), the value of attribute `name` might also be updated. You can check this as follows:

1. In the admin, go to the product edit page, and switch to store `1` using the [configuration scope box](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#configuration/scope.html). If the "Use default" checkbox is not checked, the value from store `1` is shown. Otherwise, the value from store `0` is shown.
2. In the database, you can see this in the corresponding product attribute table, in this case `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. If there is no value for the combination of store id `1`, entity id `123` and attribute id `71`, then the value for the combination of store id `0`, entity id `123` and attribute id `71` is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you actually modify the product, but if you modify it via the admin's product edit page, you should be able to get the store ID via:

```
$observer->getProduct()->getStoreId()
```

This gives you the store ID of the store in which the product has been saved (the store which is selected in the upper left store switcher).