# Event Observer for specific store

Tags: event-observer, multistore, store-view, store-id

I use this Event Observer on a multistore for a custom URL Structure [Manufacturer in product url key](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/manufacturer-in-product-url-key).
The problem is now that I need this for only one specific store id. How can I set a custom Event Observer for specific store id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just check inside the observer if you are on the right store view.

```
public function updateurl($observer)
{
    $storeId = your store id here;
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == $storeId) {
        //your code goes here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case,i am suggesting to you use `catalog_product_save_after`.

And if you want **for a particular store** then use `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getStoreId()` that give your product store id.

see why i suggest you that use `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getStoreId()`  because of this link [How can I get the correct store context in the product save observer?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64519/how-can-i-get-the-correct-store-context-in-the-product-save-observer)

**So you need to put the below condition for at your observer**

```
if ($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getStoreId() == 'Your_Match_Store_id') {
}
```

### Observer

```
class MageStack_24869_Model_Observer
{
    public function updateurl($observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()) {
            if ($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getStoreId() == 'Your_Match_Store_id') {
                $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
                $url = '';

                if (!is_null($product->getData('country_of_manufacture'))) {
                    $url .= $product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture') . '-';
                }

                if (!is_null($product->getData('sku'))) {
                    $url .= $product->getData('sku') . '-';
                }

                if(!is_null($product->getData('name'))) {
                    $url .= $product->getData('name');
                }

                $product->setData('url_key', $url);      
            }
        }
    }
}
```